# Creating a situation-dependent dictionary (hashlib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash, hashlib

The following code is part of a bigger project:

```
# Todo: automatically generate dict based
# on hashlib.algorithms_available
algorithms = {"md5":hashlib.md5,
              "sha1":hashlib.sha1,
              "sha224":hashlib.sha224,
              "sha256":hashlib.sha256,
              "sha384":hashlib.sha384,
              "sha512":hashlib.sha512,
              "sha3_224":hashlib.sha3_224,
              "sha3_256":hashlib.sha3_256,
              "sha3_384":hashlib.sha3_384,
              "sha3_512":hashlib.sha3_512,
            }
self.algo, algorithms = algorithms[self.algo], None
```

I am trying to use hashlib's `algorithms_available` (`hashlib.algorithms_available`) to create a custom dictionary, system-dependent. The `key:value` pair should be like `《algorithm name》: hashlib.《algorithm》`, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the algorithm object using [hashlib.new](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.new) and create a dict, iterating over `hashlib.algorithms_available`.

Something like this -

```
In : algorithms = {algo:hashlib.new(algo) for algo in hashlib.algorithms_available}

In : algorithms
Out:
{'DSA': <DSA HASH object @ 0x103e824b0>,
 'DSA-SHA': <DSA-SHA HASH object @ 0x103e8ac70>,
 'MD4': <MD4 HASH object @ 0x102e55470>,
 'MD5': <MD5 HASH object @ 0x103e9ddf0>,
 'MDC2': <MDC2 HASH object @ 0x103eeebb0>,
 'RIPEMD160': <RIPEMD160 HASH object @ 0x104012ef0>,
 'SHA': <SHA HASH object @ 0x103c99af0>,
 'SHA1': <SHA1 HASH object @ 0x103ef32f0>,
 'SHA224': <SHA224 HASH object @ 0x1040123b0>,
 'SHA256': <SHA256 HASH object @ 0x103e9d6f0>,
 'SHA384': <SHA384 HASH object @ 0x103ef02b0>,
 'SHA512': <SHA512 HASH object @ 0x103e9d2b0>,
 'dsaEncryption': <dsaEncryption HASH object @ 0x1040120f0>,
 'dsaWithSHA': <dsaWithSHA HASH object @ 0x103e82a30>,
 'ecdsa-with-SHA1': <ecdsa-with-SHA1 HASH object @ 0x103e9d670>,
 'md4': <md4 HASH object @ 0x102de49f0>,
 'md5': <md5 HASH object @ 0x103e8a570>,
 'mdc2': <mdc2 HASH object @ 0x103ef0db0>,
 'ripemd160': <ripemd160 HASH object @ 0x103ef09b0>,
 'sha': <sha HASH object @ 0x102dfb4b0>,
 'sha1': <sha1 HASH object @ 0x103b532b0>,
 'sha224': <sha224 HASH object @ 0x103e9d7b0>,
 'sha256': <sha256 HASH object @ 0x103eee770>,
 'sha384': <sha384 HASH object @ 0x103ef7bf0>,
 'sha512': <sha512 HASH object @ 0x103e9d6b0>}
```